# "younger face" or "younger looks"

Tags: phrase-request

(1) I haven't met Jack for at least twenty years. Yesterday, I received his photo in my email. I don't remember **how he looked when he was youngers.** (my original example)

(2) I haven't met Jack for at least twenty years. Yesterday, I received his photo in my email. I don't remember his **younger face**.

(3) I haven't met Jack for at least twenty years. Yesterday, I received his photo in my email. I don't remember his **younger looks**.

I want to replace the highlighted words in (1) with a shorter phrase. Do "younger face" and "younger looks" work?

Comment: This use of ***looks*** is "unusual", to say the least (it would be *less* unusual as singular ***look***, but even that wouldn't be common in the exact cited context). On purely stylistic grounds I suggest sticking with ***how he looked*** - or better, ***what he looked like***. It's hardly worth bothering to explicitly mention ***when he was younger***, since it's contextually implicit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, not directly addressing the question, but about "met"**:

"I haven't met Jack for ..." is a bit awkward putting "met" in present perfect tense like that and specifying a duration.

Plain "met" sort of implies the initial meeting/introduction, as in "I haven't met Jack yet" (but I hope to one day, etc.). But applying a duration as you are, it would be more natural to use "I haven't *seen* Jack for at least twenty years".

On the other hand, if you add "with" as in "I haven't met *with* Jack for at least twenty years", it's closer to what you are intending, but "met with" is more appropriate for appointments/meetings such as in a professional context, whereas with friends it might be "met up with" (informally, bordering on slang?).

**On to your question of shortening "I don't remember how he looked when he was youngers"**

1 ("how he looked when he was youngers") is OK, though it would be "younger" and not "youngers". You are trying to make this shorter, so you just saved one character :)

2 ("remember his younger face") is bit awkward.

3 ("remember his younger looks") is most awkward. "Younger looks" doesn't sound right in this possessive context.

You can try more creative phrasing like "I don't remember his youthful visage", though this feels like trying too hard.

**About "I don't remember..."**

Another tweak to the phrasing to make it fit more naturally in your paragraph: "I didn't even remember ..."

The past tense of "didn't" is wrapping around the previous sentence's "yesterday", the point at which you received the photo. This flows more naturally.

**Summary**

Possibly not the best writing, but definitely natural:

*I haven't seen Jack for at least twenty years. Yesterday, I received his photo in my email. I didn't even remember how he looked when he was younger.*